# What's the relationship between TypeScript as "installed into" VS 2019 and the one used by npm and gulp?

Tags: typescript

I don't understand how or where TypeScript is installed on my PC.

I have TypeScript `^3.9.9` specified in my npm `package.json` and that's used by `gulp-typescript` to compile everything. But I understand from the TypeScript docs that it's also installed into Visual Studio 2019*.

Inside VS, when I right-click my project and open its properties, on the TypeScript Build tab, I can pick from a bunch of versions so I've chosen 4.2 because 3.9.9 isn't available and 3.1 seems too old.

While I understand how Gulp and NPM works and that its files are under `node_modules` I can't understand how TS can be "installed into" VS and how to sort out this weird dual version thing or why I even need both?

Can someone shed some light on this? How can I make them the same version? Does it matter?

--

*NB - Strictly speaking it doesn't say this, it only mentions VS2017 and 2015.3

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-tooling-in-5-minutes.html

Comment: If you have TS listed as a dependency in package.json, then it's downloaded and installed in node_modules. VS is just plain weird and I wouldn't suggest using it. IIRC it only uses its built in version to check your code but that doesn't actually correspond to the version it should be using. You should be able to make it behave like a proper editor and use your package.json + project config but by default it doesn't and it drove me up the wall. I just use VSCode myself.

Comment: Funny, I'm having problems in some other area now and I thought, hmm, I should probably use VS2019 for backend and VSCode for frontend but I'm trying to avoid a SPA architecture. It all broke when I updated to latest VS2019. The complexity of a modern website is completely exhausting.

Comment: It's only rivalled by the complexity of the modern VS. I opened the frontend project at work with VS *by accident* and though "OK, I'll just wait for it to unfreeze and close it". I had to kill the process when my computer approached the melting point because VS decided to run, like, 5 or more NPM processes and compile/check/who knows what the TS code. I don't know exactly what it did, just that I had 98% memory consumed, most of it by VS.